# Why does nth_value function in BigQuery on display for rows >= n?

Tags: google-bigquery

Code below produces result where variable nt4 is null for rows 1,2, and 3.  This looks strange.  Is this a bug?  The value should be 'of' for all of the rows in the window function.

```
SELECT
   word,
   word_count, corpus,
   NTH_VALUE(word,4) OVER (PARTITION BY corpus ORDER BY word_count DESC) nt4,
   rank(word) over (PARTITION BY corpus ORDER BY word_count DESC) rank
FROM
   [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. It is as expected

The reason is  - if you use ORDER BY without specifying ROWS or RANGE, ORDER BY implies that the window extends from the beginning of the partition to the current row. See [Window functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions) for details

Meantime, quick explanation:

For example, for "`kinghenryviii`" partition
The first row has window with just one row with word - "`the`"
Second row has two rows in window - "`the`" and "`I`"
Third - "`the`", "`I`" and "`and`"

So far as you see there is no 4th row here thus the value is null

For forth row thare are four rows in window - "`the`", "`I`", "`and`" and "`of`"
For fifth  - "`the`", "`I`", "`and`", "`of`" and "`to`"

As you see, starting with forth rows - forth value IS available and it is "`of`"

Hope this is clear and helped you

Comment: But `LEAD` doesn't' return null.  Are the semantics of the window different for different functions?